# How to set ProgressBar at the center screen in frame layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using following code, but my progress bar is not displaying in the center of frame layout. I want to avoid padding to my progressbar.Can any one please explain? It is perfectly working if i am using "Linear Layout"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">

    <ProgressBar android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/gallery_img"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

 </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: you have set the gravity for framelayout, instead if you want the progress bar to be in center set its gravity

Comment: I try this to, but its not working...

Answer (score 45, accepted):

In the layout xml for your progressBar set the `android:layout_gravity` (instead of `android:gravity`) to `"center"`

```
android:layout_gravity = "center"
```

Comment: Setting this in layout xml works for me too, but, I was surpised, that ProgressBar does not have setGravity() method.

Comment: Along with this. Use layout_gravity  in Progressbar.:)

Comment: Not sure in 2010, but right now, ProgressBar doesn't have a gravity attribute.

Comment: You should use [layout_gravity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_gravity) instead of just [gravity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html#gravity). Also you can use just `center` instead of `center_vertical|center_horizontal`.

Comment: Ok, here is quote from official android documentation for [FrameLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html): "... You can, however, add multiple children to a FrameLayout and control their position within the FrameLayout by assigning gravity to each child, using the **android:layout_gravity** attribute."

Comment: I would do the following however it's only a solution if you don't mind hiding your entire layout while your data is loading:
1) Put a relative layout in your .xml file 
2) Set its layout parameters to match parent
3) Give it an id
4) Put the progress bar widget inside the relative layout
5) Control the visibility of the layout in your activity/fragment

Answer (score 42):

Use

```
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
```

Example:

```
 <ProgressBar android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
     android:layout_centerVertical="true"
     android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
```

`android:gravity` attribute is not supported on `ProgressBar`

Comment: Those parameters you said are specific for RelativeLayout.

Comment: the layout_centerInParent works indeed very well for Relative Layouts! , gravity does not work.

Comment: Better answer than the selected!

Comment: Invalid layout param in a FrameLayout: layout_centerHorizontal adn other

Comment: This is the up-to-date solution and works. However not valid for FrameLayout, gives warning

Answer (score 13):

`FrameLayout` does not have `android:gravity`. You need to set `android:layout_gravity` on the `ProgressBar` instead.

Answer (score 9):

```
<ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ***android:layout_gravity="center"*** />
```

add this line in

```
 <ProgressBar
              android:layout_gravity="center" />
```

Comment: This is actually the only correct answer for this question.

Comment: This is the correct and most simple working solution, should have more upvotes

Answer (score 5):

Just change your Layout as RelativeLayout and add android:layout_centerInParent="true"
to your ProgressBar.

```
<ProgressBar
android:id="@+id/progBar"
android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/my_progress_indeterminate"
android:layout_height="50dp" 
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
android:layout_width="50dp">
</ProgressBar>
```

Answer (score 5):

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    />
```

Comment: Although this code might (or might not) solve the problem, a good answer should explain what the code does and how it solves the problem.

Answer (score 2):

As of 2018, you need to set the below attribute:

```
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

Working solution as of 2017

```
android:layout_gravity="center"
```

Answer (score -3):

you must set the postion in pixels as in framelayout different components overlap each other. So, you can try it by setting pixels in dip.